# Why will two Tkinter buttons which are side by side change distance on resizing the window? How could this be fixed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some Python code, using Tkinter, and I have tried to place two buttons side by side. It works, but once the window is resized, the buttons change their distance from each other. I have tried to make it work with pack, but it has not succeeded. Note: I would like to not use grid, as my full app does not.

Code:

```
root=Tk()
root.geometry('350x350')
Button(root, text='button1').place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
Button(root, text='button2').place(relx=0.6, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put the two buttons in a frame.

Comment: good idea. I'll try that!